# Mean of Cosine similarities (Word2Vec) of word pairs sets in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, word2vec, cosine-similarity

I am working in Python with a dictionary in this form:

> ```
>  {
>      1:[(word1, word2), (word3, word4)],
>      2:[(word5, word6), (word7, word8), (word9, word10)],
>      3:[(word11, word12), (word13, word14)]
> }
> ```

I am computing the cosine similarity of each word pair (using Word2Vec), indexed by key as following:

```
> def get_sim(data, key=int):
>     for key in data:
>         for w1, w2 in temp[1]:
>             print(key, w1, w2, wv.similarity(w1, w2))
get_sim(temp)
```

from which I get this kind of result:

> ```
> 1, word1, word2, cos_sim
> ```

My question: for all similarity scores associated to each key (cos_sim values), I want to compute the mean value (like a final score). Could list comprehension help?

My practical question: which would be a suitable module to work with the datatype above? I tried with json but it transforms my keys (and cos_sim values) in strings, which I definitely don't want. Even using int(key) doesn't help. Pandas and numpy, on the other hand, don't work very good with strings which are my 2nd and 3rd entry in the line.

I am relatively new to programming, so thank you very much for any hint which will me help further!

Comment: For the question of ‘can I?’, the answer is a definite yes. I’m not sure what you mean by “level”; the issue is scope. Your `get_sim` function doesn’t have information about what the key is, because you’ve only passed in the corresponding list of values. One option is to pass both. You may want to try this out and narrow down your question to something more specific. (See [ask].)

Comment: Thank you! I guess my issue is exactly I don't understand (in general) how to pass info in a function. What about nesting a for loop in a for loop? Like:

for key in temp:
  for w1, w2 in key:

I'll try if iy works. It's trivial but as said, I'm very new to programming.

Comment: Hi, I tried as following and it works!!! Thank you <3

def get_sim(data, key=int):
    for key in data:
        for w1, w2 in temp[1]:
            print(key, w1, w2, wv.similarity(w1, w2))

Now I'm up to find a function to compute the mean of cos_sim sorted by key :)